# Spring 2.0.2 Build war file using gradle

Tags: rest, spring-boot, tomcat, war

I utilized the following to develop a Restful application.

- jdk1.8.0_171
- tomcat 8.5(servlet 3.1)
- Spring boot 2.0.2 to

I built a war file by doing below three things:

1. made main class to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` and overrode  its configure method
2. add `apply plugin: 'war`' to `build.gradle`
3. add `providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'` to dependencies in `build.gradle`

I started application by executing `java -jar MyApp.war`. The application can be accessed from any browser. But when the same war file was deployed to tomcat server, I got 404 error when I tried to access the application from a browser. There is no error in log.

Anyone has idean? Thanks!

Comment: What the URL used to access it? What's the war name on tomcat?

Comment: Thank you Luis for your reminder. I forgot to put war name in the path.